# Can I use multiple results from MySQL query in Apache2 mod_rewrite?

Tags: mysql, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to control access with Apache2 mod_rewrite. Specifically I only want to allow certain IPs for accessing my site.

I understand that I can use file such as

```
RewriteMap    hosts-allow  "txt:/path/to/hosts.txt"
```

And I have read that I can also use SQL query, but apparently it only works for one result and if multiple rows are returned then it uses a random one. Is there some way to use multiple results?

Otherwise, do I have to automate saving IPs from my MySQL to file all by myself to use multiple results?

If yes then does Apache2 automatically flush cache of the file whenever it changes?

Any insights are very welcome, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work.

If you have a similiar problem then your Apache2 file 000-default.conf (look up the location of this file on your Linux distro) has to look like this.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    DBDriver mysql
    DBDParams "host=localhost,user=root,pass=password,dbname=name"

    RewriteMap whitelist "dbd:SELECT ip FROM users WHERE ip = %h LIMIT 1"

    <Directory /var/www>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond "${whitelist:%{REMOTE_ADDR}|FOUND}" "FOUND"
        RewriteRule "^" "" [F]
    </Directory>

    ...

</VirtualHost>
```

Now to explain a bit

```
RewriteMap whitelist "dbd:SELECT ip FROM users WHERE ip = %h"
```

Parameter %h in here stands for IP address of request, so it doesn't use multiple results from SQL query, but since WHERE will only return rows when it's condition is met then it can work for any amount of IP's.

```
RewriteCond "${whitelist:%{REMOTE_ADDR}|FOUND}" "FOUND"
```

The :%{REMOTE_ADDR} searches for REMOTE_ADDR in the whitelist, which will most likely contain IP address only when it was found with SQL query, otherwise it's empty.

```
RewriteRule "^" "" [F]
```

Here [F] means forbidden, you can set it to for example [R] to redirect, but you have to look up more information on how to use it, and "^" means that this rule is being applied to all URLs.

The empty "" is a key delimeter (?) that Apache2 expects in .txt maps, but since we use SQL query then we got none in here.

If you want to use mod_dbd with MySQL then you have to install a package (for example on Debian 8)

```
sudo apt-get install libaprutil1-dbd-mysql
```

Or otherwise Apache2 won't start start after setting DBDriver to mysql

You have to also enable mod_rewrite and mod_dbd in Apache2 with

```
a2enmod rewrite
a2enmod dbd
```

Hope it was helpful for someone :)